# Convert Active Record Object and String Attributes to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-2.2

I am trying to convert a Rails record into a fully Javascript-traversable JSON object. I can convert the basic record into JSON just fine, and I can convert each individual attribute into JSON just fine. However, I don't have a good way to convert the entire object into a traversable JSON object. Ideally the solution would not involve iterating over each attribute and converting the value to JSON. How can I completely convert my entire record into a JSON format that I can fully traverse in Javascript?

Below are the steps you would need to take to replicate my problem. Thanks in advance.

```
# database
MySQL, and the column is a Rails text data type.

# seeds.rb
ModelName.create(
  has_hash_value: { one: { two: { three: "content"} } }
)

# console
$ rake db:seed

# controller
@resource = ModelName.first.to_json

# erb view
<div id="data" data-json="<$= @resource %>"></div>

# generated HTML
{"has_hash_value":"{:one=\u003e{:two=\u003e{:three=\u003e\"content\"}}}",

# javascript
window.data = $('#data').data().json

# browser console
> data.has_hash_value
< "{:one=>{:two=>{:three=>"content"}}}"
> data.has_hash_value.one
< undefined
```

**Update**

I've tried `@resource = JSON.parse(ModelName.first.to_json)`, but what is returned is a completely untraversable string. The nested hash is formatted better, however.

```
# controller
@resource = JSON.parse(ModelName.first.to_json)

# generated HTML
data-json="{"has_hash_value"=>"{:one=>{:two=>{:three=>\"content\"}}}"

# browser console
> data.has_hash_value
< undefined
```

**Update 2**

When I seed with the data formatted as either a string or as json, and convert to hash then JSON in the controller, the generated HTML and JS response are cleaner, but I still cannot fully traverse.

```
# seeds.rb
has_hash_value: { one: { two: { three: "content"} } }.to_json

# controller
@resource = TourAnalytic.first.as_json.to_json

# generated HTML
data-json="{"has_hash_value":"{\"one\":{\"two\":{\"three\":\"content\"}}}"

# browser console
> data.has_hash_value
< Object {has_hash_value: "{"one":{"two":{"three":"content"}}}"}
> data.has_hash_value.one
< undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the value of `has_hash_value`. It's a string (wrapped in "s). This is what I did:

```
your_hash = { has_hash_value: { one: { two: { three: "content"} } }.to_json }
your_hash[:has_hash_value] = JSON.parse(your_hash[:has_hash_value]
```

Your hash will then have the value:

`{:has_hash_value=>{"one"=>{"two"=>{"three"=>"content"}}}}`

I **strongly** suggest moving all of this code to the model and overwriting the `#to_json` method.

Comment: This may work for one attribute at a time, but I can already convert each attribute individually to JSON, and I have 20 attributes or so that need conversion per record. I was hoping there was a way to more simply parse the ActiveRecord object in its entirety.